# EXCEL problem. How to compare numbers in three columns and show the highest one?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel question.

I have some products in A,B,C warehouses. How Can I compare the numbers in these warehouses and show the warehouse with the highest number?

[Here's the Excel example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BH4d2.png)

I tried If function but it didn't work.

Comment: `=@SORTBY(B$1:D$1,B2:D2,-1)`

Answer (score 1):

Recordig to your table, use `=INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MATCH(MAX(B2:D2),B2:D2,0))` to get the name of warehouse with the highest number.

Answer (score 0):

Please try Max function

Add below in E2 cell output should be 432 (or highest in 3 columns)

```
=MAX(B2:D2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to find Max Value, you just need to use MAX function instead of if function.

you need to put the following in E2, E3, E4 column respectively.

```
=MAX(B2:D2)          
=MAX(B3:D3)
=MAX(B4:D4)
```

Refer to this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/max-function-e0012414-9ac8-4b34-9a47-73e662c08098#:%7E:text=The%20MAX%20function%20syntax%20has,to%20find%20the%20maximum%20value.) by microsoft.